# Loading custom widget script in third party web pages and isolating dynamically called jQuery script

Tags: jquery

I have a custom widget script library used for search purpose,which will execute dynamically. My custom library contains codes for writing  primary jQuery tags(like 1.7.2.js) and other html elements need for search purpose including some date picker controls. When call this custom script in third party web page, script tags will be written in page head element and load search panel.This works fine when calling the script in simple HTML  and ASPX pages, but when call this script in a pages having more HTML content, script error raises.
Errors are: `$.widget is not a function()...` and `$(...).datepicker() is not a function` etc.The problem is with `jquery.ui.1.10.2.js` which loads next after `jquery.1.2.min.js`.

I just called this way:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Search.aspx.cs"     Inherits="Location.Search" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">  
    <script src="https://mycustomwidget.js"></script> //This script will load all basic sript tag includes jquery min,jqueryUI and css links
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <label>Search here</label>
      <input type="text" class="customsearch"></input>       
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: check if you didn't include twice jquery

Comment: I have checked the content,seems the tags loaded only once like this:

<head>
    <script src="  <script src="https://mycustomwidget.js"></script>"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>I have checked the ui content,seems all tags loaded only once like below:

Comment: did you try to load your customwidget.js after jquery?

Comment: That's not the way am looking for.My requirement is to load the jquery and ui scripts within my customwidget.js

I even tried this link: http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery,but no luck.